# Doctrine : dynamic parameters.yml for each user

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After many search in this forum and on others i didn't find a solution to my problem so i hope you can help me a little bit
Here is the situation

I have a website : www.test.com

I have a X client connecting to this website who are using their own database (same database structure)
 - client1db
 - client2db
 .....

Each time i have a new client(company), I have to create his own database

On other side, i have a list of user for each of those client

I can't change how this mechanism is build so i have to find a solution to deal with it

I have a config.yml with databse information
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default

```
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%test_driver%"
            host:     "%test_host%"
            port:     "%test_port%"
            dbname:   "%test_name%"
            user:     "%test_user%"
            password: "%test_password%"
```

and a parameters.yml to set the value

Every parameters are common to all my customer, just the host is changing

I would like to configure when a customer from company 1 log the host is client1db, when a customer from company 2 the host is client2db
Of course multiple customer from all company must have acces at the same time.

So my problem is how i can link the database host to the user ?
Can we build the parameters for each user ?

---

An other solution can be to create as one connection for each client in the config.yml but here come an other problem, how can i set the default_connection a log user ?

---

I didn't find any realiable solution, so i would like any help or advice to where should i look for a solution

Thanks for help

Comment: I've found this, but I'm not yet sure how to use it to solve your problem http://blog.dixo.net/2015/02/dynamic-configuration-of-doctrine-and-other-services-in-symfony/

Answer (score 0):

If im getting your question right, I believe you want dynamic variable names. I had a similar project once, what i did is that I created an array with all the keys that I could possibly have like:

```
$keys = array("value1","value2","value3","value4");
```

Then I had a looping mechanism to go through the array and assign it to the variable names:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($keys)-1; $i++) {
     $var = $keys[$i];
     ${substr($var,0)} = ' ';
}
```

That way, we have a different variable name for each user.